# PGFPLOT Help Required for joint and marginal pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, languages, technical-drawing

[image: joint pdf two independent normal random variables]I have made the first two figures in Matlab of two independent normal random variables. If somebody can help me to make them in Latex pgfplots. I am novice in pdfplots.

I have used these equations for the plots

(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(x-1).^2/2)

(1/(2*pi)).*(exp(-((X-1).^2/2)-((Y-1).^2/2)))

Third figure is a hand written sketch taken from internet, if somebody can regenerate it in pgfplots.

Joint PDF of two independent normal random variables with mean and variance equal to 1[image: Marginal pdf of two independent normal random variables with mean and variance equal to 1[![Rough sketch taken from Internet] ][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DK4c.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DK4c.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 3):

This is to give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    f(\x,\y)=(1/(2*pi))*exp(-pow(\x-1,2)/2-pow(\y-1,2)/2);}]
 \begin{axis}[zmax=1/pi,zmin=-1/pi,colormap/viridis]
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-1/pi]
   \draw[color of colormap=900] (1,1) circle[radius=0.5];
   \draw[color of colormap=700] (1,1) circle[radius=1];
   \draw[color of colormap=500] (1,1) circle[radius=1.5];
   \draw[color of colormap=300] (1,1) circle[radius=2];
   \draw[color of colormap=100] (1,1) circle[radius=2.5];
  \end{scope}
  \addplot3[color=red,thick,samples y=0,domain=-2:4] (x,4,{f(x,1)}); 
  \addplot3[color=blue,thick,samples y=0,domain=-2:4] (-2,x,{f(1,x)}); 
  \addplot3[mesh,domain=-2:4,domain y=-2:4] {f(x,y)}; 
  \addplot3[color=red,thick,samples y=0,domain=4:-2] (x,1,{f(x,1)})
   -- (-2,1,{f(1,1)}); ; 
  \addplot3[color=blue,thick,samples y=0,domain=-2:4] (1,x,{f(1,x)}) --
  (1,4,{f(1,1)}); 
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Refer some source to learn it.

Comment: @RajaAliRiaz The pgfplots manual.

Comment: Thank you obliged

Comment: when I run the code in overleaf it is not showing circles in xy plane. and giving no error as well.

Comment: @RajaAliRiaz It looks like overleaf uses a very old TeX installation, in which the `canvas is xy plane at z` key had a bug. Tell them to treat their users better.

Comment: is there any alternative for canvas, which is the best IDE for latex in which I do not have to add the packages. Previously I used to use Kile on Ubuntu but adding packages were nightmare.

Comment: Honestly speaking I have got no problems with overleaf till date but this time around faced with this bug.

Comment: @RajaAliRiaz Well, glad to hear that you had no issues so far. However, all I can say is that I presented here a working code, and now receive all the messages because overleaf screws up. You can use `canvas is yx plane` here, but the *way* cleaner solution would be if overleaf were to clean up.

Comment: I am sorry, if you feel offended, I have no affections for overleaf. I am just a novice user. Nevertheless I am obliged for your time. I am sure your code is right problem is with the execution of the platform. Regards

Comment: Schrondinger's cat thank you and stackexchange as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am extremely thankful to Schrondinger cat helping starting coder. I have generated the pgfplots.

[image: joint pdf [![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5qvj.jpg)